# How to get a String from searchView on ToolBar?

Tags: java, kotlin

I need to get a String from searchView on ToolBar for filtering, I complete the filtering but ı can't get the String from ToolBar.

Here is my searchView

```
<item
        android:title="Search"
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        />
```

Here is my RecylerAdapter

```
  val userInput: String = ""
        val filteredList: List<Book> = bookList.filter {
            it.bookName.contains(userInput)
        }
```

So I need userInput.

Comment: Where are you accessing the data from your search item?

Comment: Try applying getQuery() method to your SearchView object, I'm not android dev but you can try

Comment: @tomerpacific ı didnt understand your question bro

Answer (score 0):

Just like [Gius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13312696/gius) mentioned, you have to use the `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.getQuery()` method, like this:

```
val searchView = view?.findViewById<SearchView>(R.id.searchView)
if(searchView != null) {
    val filteredList: List<Book> = bookList.filter {
        it.bookName.contains(searchView.query) == true
    }
}
```

Comment: Unresolved reference: view. Error1


Type mismatch.
Required:
Boolean
Found:
Unit
Error 2

Comment: just corrected the answer, I forgot about the "== true" part

Comment: everything okey but 
Unresolved reference: view still error

Comment: Where do you want to put this code, in a fragment?

Comment: Nope, on my BookRecylerAdapter.kt

Comment: does the BookRecyclerView exist in MainActivity?

Comment: Just User Operations in MainActivity

Comment: You could put the "val searchView = view?.findViewById<SearchView>(R.id.searchView)" in the fragment where you initialize the adapter. Then pass the searchView as a parameter to the adapter constructor.